# PHP won't open files in Ubuntu LAMP web application

Tags: php, lamp

I am working a LAMP web app running on Ubuntu 11.10.
I followed instructions on the web to harden my apache, php and mysql.

I have a PHP script which work fine when I run from the command line under my own id.  But when I put the scripts into the web app framework, it can't not even open a log file to write (in /tmp) and it can't read other files in /var/www/myapp/html as well.

I used Ajax to retrieve file contents on the server and then serve those files to the browser.  So my url will look like:  "php/myphpscript.php?arg=.......".

My directory structure is
/var/www/myapp/html|php|js|cfg.

I know this problem has something to do with permission, security but I am quite at loss. 
Can someone describe what I need to do here?

Thanks,

Comment: Start off by checking the Apache error-log: `/var/log/apache/error.log`. Then you will know what actually happened.

Comment: try to change your permissions on htdocs, without permission you won't do nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you copied the files with your username, but apache executes as user www-data an thus has no access to your files. Either change them to belong to the apache user, or if you are the only develper on this machine, cahnge apache to run as you.

Comment: +1. i think you should provide an example to change user / group permissions though

Comment: OK: as root edit /etc/apache2/envvars and change export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data resp. export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data to whatever you need, e.g. export APACHE_RUN_USER=john resp. export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=users

Comment: I think it's cleaner to add yourself to www-data group and give group permission to edit (write) files.

Comment: Sure it is, but depending on wether your php.ini settings force a UID or a GID check, it might not be enough. 
I prefixed my suggestion with "if you are the only develper on this machine"

Comment: In my Ubuntu, all files are owned by root and I happened to some php scrips copied into /var/www/.. under my id.  That is the reason why those scripts can be executed using my id (another root-capable id) but can not be executed as part of the web app.  As suggested by rzetterberg, always check the apache log files first.  There are a lot of useful information in those file